# Angular - React to content rendered after Navigation

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have an angular application with several different components and pages that display user-created html-content.
After the content is completely loaded, i need to search it for specific elements and add an onclick-event to them.

So my idea was to subscribe to the router and react to NavigationEnd-Events for screening the DOM. Problem: The DOM isn't ready on NavigationEnd.

I also can't use document.ready since it only fires on the first page-load, and apparently i can't use lifecycle hooks unless i put them in every single component.

My current attempt is in a service and looks like this:

```
  setupClickEventSubscription(){
    this.router.events
      .subscribe(e => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          //returns nothing because DOM not ready
          document.querySelectorAll('[click-event]').forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener('click', this.clickFunction.bind(this))
          })
        }
      })
  }
```

I'd need something like a global "Document ready again"- Subscription. Am i missing something?

Comment: Why not use the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook on a component level to add your events? Trying to hack something 'globally' seems to create more problems than it solves imo

Comment: because i would have to do it in literally every component and if someone was to introduce a new one and forgets it, the feature doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at ViewChild e.g. ViewChildren - may look something like:

```
@ViewChildren(SomeDirective) elemets: QueryList<SomeDirective>
```

Or with Template Element-References:

```
@ViewChildren("whatEverRef", { read: ElementRef }) whatEverRef: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Template:

`<li #whatEverRef>yo</li>`

Comment: viewchildren do not support HTML-Attribute-Selectors

Comment: I think you may use ElementRefs, though. 
@ViewChildren("whatEverRef", { read: ElementRef }) whatEverRef: QueryList<ElementRef>;
Template:
<li #whatEverRef>yo</li>

Or something like this.

Comment: i cannot add anything to the html tags because they are part of dynamic content that some admin user inputs